# React TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__.PropTypes is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am making a react app using routers and I'm getting the following error:

> React TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react**.PropTypes is
> undefined

How can I avoid it?

Here the code for the 2 routers, post and profile:

**Posts**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';


class Posts extends Component{
    render(){
        return <div>  Posts </div>
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

**Profile**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';


class Profile extends Component{
    render(){
        return <div>  Profile </div>
    }
}

export default Profile;
```

**index.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

//COMPONENTS
import Posts from './Components/posts';
import Profile from './Components/profile';


class App extends Component{

    render(){
        return <div> home </div>

    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
    <Route path="/posts" component={Posts}>  </Route>

    <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}>  </Route>

    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
    ,document.querySelector('#root'))
```

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of React are you using?

I got this error when upgrading to React 16, and changing my react lines in package.json to:

```
"react-dom": "^15.1.1",
"react": "^15.1.1",
```

and then running `npm install` and `npm start` fixed it for me.

Comment: How can downgrading possibly be the right solution to this issue?

Comment: @silkfire IKR?! This is a workaround until React fixes the issue.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem and late noticed that I had a typo in my import statement.

Instead of:

```
import React from "react"
```

I had:

```
import {React} from "react"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5.
>   [Please use the prop-types library instead.](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include descriptive prose to explain why this addressed the original asker's question? –

Answer (score 1):

I modified version of these packages in packages.json file

```
"react": "^0.14.7",
"react-dom": "^0.14.7",
"react-redux": "^5.1.0",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
```

then run "npm install" and "npm start" its working

Answer (score 0):

fixed it in "react-dom": "^16.6.3",by changing

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';    
class App extends Component{
render(){
    return <div> home </div>
  }
}
```

to

```
import React from 'react';    
class App extends React.Component{
render(){
    return <div> home </div>
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the fix was to replace `class FooBar extends React.component {` with `class FooBar extends React.Component {`