# TypeError: _ClassName__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.ClassName is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs

I want to understand what I am doing wrong by defining some objects in a different file than where they are used.

In App.tsx shown below, `GlobalSettings` and `GlobalContext` are commented out. They are instead imported  from ./GlobalSettings.

If I un-comment the commented lines and remove the import my app works as expected.

If I run the app as it is shown below I get an error on this line in App.tsx: `var s = new GlobalSettings():

> TypeError: *GlobalSettings__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7*_.GlobalSettings is not a constructor

Based on the [research I did into the error msg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor) it appears that since `GlobalSettings` has a public constructor defined I should not get this error.

Also, [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973884/typeerror-aws-amplify-core-webpack-imported-module-8-aws-dynamodb-is-not) appears to be due to missing constructor.

None of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655272/react-typeerror-webpack-imported-module-0-react-proptypes-is-undefined) address the problem I am posting unless there is an ongoing bug in React, which seems doubtful.

App.tsx

```
import { GlobalSettings, GlobalContext } from './GlobalSettings';

//class GlobalSettings  {
//    public UserName: string = "";
//    public CustomerID: string = "";
//    public SubscriptionID: string = "";
//};

var s = new GlobalSettings();
s.UserName = "Sam";
s.CustomerID = "x";
s.SubscriptionID = "y";

//export const GlobalContext = React.createContext<GlobalSettings>(s);

function App() {

  return (
          <GlobalContext.Provider value={s}>
            //...
          </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

GlobalSettings.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

export class GlobalSettings {
    public UserName: string = "";
    public CustomerID: string = "";
    public SubscriptionID: string = "";

    public constructor() { }
};

var s = new GlobalSettings();
s.UserName = "Sam";
s.CustomerID = "x";
s.SubscriptionID = "y";

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext<GlobalSettings>(s);
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.52",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "msal": "^1.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "use-async-effect": "^2.2.2"
  },
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do you use './GlobalSettings' in some other place or it is used only in `App.tsx`?

Comment: @Shlang thanks for your response.  In attempting to create a repro I solved the issue.  Root cause unknown.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by deleting node_modules folder and package-lock.json and running `npm install`. I cannot reproduce it again.